# Apt-Get system completely broken. possible to completely reinstall it?

Tags: apt

I just recently noticed my apt-get system is broken. I have tried everything I can to fix it but everything I'm told just ends up with a message saying that the apt-get system is corrupt and unfixable. When I try to install a package, it says it can't find it. How can I completely reinstall apt-get? Is there even such a thing?

Comment: could you please do a sudo apt-get update and copy paste the result

Comment: What is your Ubuntu architecture? amd64 or i386?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can download apt packages from Ubuntu repos and install them manually.

At first, create a directory in `~/Downloads` and go into it:

```
mkdir ~/Downloads/apt-packs
cd ~/Downloads/apt-packs
```

And then download all apt packages corresponding to your architecture (amd64 or i386). For example, you have amd64 (Ubuntu 64bit):

Download following deb packages for apt (apt and its dependencies):

```
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apt/libapt-inst2.0_1.1.5_amd64.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apt/libapt-pkg5.0_1.1.5_amd64.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apt/apt-utils_1.1.5_amd64.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apt/apt_1.1.5_amd64.deb
```

Finally, install them all with `dpkg`:

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

Comment: I replace the version  from 1.1.5 to 1.2.25 and it works too

Comment: @YuJiaao yes that was the version I provided at that time. Now you can use the latest version.