# Broken APT on WSL 18.04

Tags: apt, 18.04, snap, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am having problems with apt on my WSL installation of Ubuntu 18.04.

Whenever I try to install a package with apt I get this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required: [...]

E: Could not read response to hello message from hook [ ! -f /usr/bin/snap ] || /usr/bin/snap advise-snap --from-apt 2>/dev/null || true: Success
E: Could not read response to hello message from hook [ ! -f /usr/bin/snap ] || /usr/bin/snap advise-snap --from-apt 2>/dev/null || true: Success
```

I believe snapd/snappy is the culprit here, but I have not been able to find a way to solve this. Afaik snapd is not supported on WSL and I assume it's been installed in an update.

I am hoping to find a solution that won't require me to nuke the whole installation and having to spend hours setting everything up fresh.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: original output from `apt --version` was `apt 1.6.8 (amd64)`. An upgrade to `1.7.0 (amd64)` did **not** seem to fix the issue.

Comment: Related: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+bug/1776218 Should be fixed already…

Comment: I've read that thread, but it doesn't really help me in any way. This problem appeared recently for me (after using the wsl installation for a good 4-5 months.)
Is there any way to update apt itself (without apt upgrade)?

Comment: Yes, you could use `dpkg`. Download the required package from https://packages.ubuntu.com/, then [install it manually](https://askubuntu.com/a/712227/250300). You should also add the output of `apt --version` to your question.

Comment: Ok, it output `apt 1.6.8 (amd64)` so I downloaded and upgraded to `apt 1.7.0 (amd64)` after resolving dependencies I still have issues.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

If you want a quick and dirty fix, you can remove the offending apt hook by typing:

```
sudo rm -rf /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20snapd.conf
```

Comment: Quick and dirty, but it did the trick.

Comment: well done. it works like a charm.

Comment: Don't forget to backup your file before removing

Comment: It would have better if you explain it a bit, like what you're up to. What is in that file just things like that, it would have much easier to understand. Thanks however it resolved my issue +1 for that.

Comment: as JPR said make a copy `sudo cp 20snapd.conf 20snapd.conf~`, install abd, and then rename the copy to the original `sudo mv 20snapd.conf~ 20snapd.conf`.

Comment: I just ran into this on Ubuntu 20.04 as well and this fixed it.  `sudo mv 20snapd.conf 20snapd.conf-removed`.